# splitting column at start of regex match

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I want to use `tidyr::separate_wider_regex` to split a column into two based on the first occurrence of a matched pattern. This is for address cleaning (splitting unit/apartment info from the building address) so there will be multiple possible matches which initiate the split but never occurring at the beginning of the address string.

This is what I have:

```
regexpr <- "(?=\\s+(?:Apt|APT|Unit|FL|#))"
df %>%
  separate_wider_regex(cols = street_name,
                       patterns = c(street = ".*", regexpr, unit= ".*"),
                       cols_remove = FALSE,
                       too_few = "debug")
```

Which works for strings like
`123 Cherry St Apt 5`

but not for the following, where it separates on the last match ("# 5"):
`123 Cherry St Apt # 5`

How do I correct the regex? Also, how can i specify non-case sensitivity so that I do not need to repeat variations like Apt and APT?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

```r
separate_wider_regex(cols = street_name, patterns = c(street = ".*?", "\\s+", unit = "(?i:Apt|Unit|FL|#).*"), cols_remove = FALSE)
```

The case insensitivity can be achieved with inline regex modifiers or regex modifier groups, here, `(?i:Apt|Unit|FL|#)` is a [regex modifier group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) where each pattern alternative is case insensitive.

The `patterns = c(street = ".*?", "\\s+", unit = "(?i:Apt|Unit|FL|#).*")` part will match any text till the first occurrence of the separator pattern into `street` column, then the whitepsace separator pattern matches the first set of whitespaces, then the rest into `unit` field, `Apt`/`Unit`/`FL` or `#` and then any  zero or more chars till end of the line.